# Team city breaks build based on code coverage

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage

That's basically the idea. I own a project and I want to break any new build on **TeamCity** based on a code coverage percentage. As simply as: *this percentage can never go down*. This way I ensure that new commits are covered.

Comment: The term for a process that only allows a metric to go in one direction is usually called a *ratchet* (after the mechanical tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity provides this out of the box.  Simply go to the configuration for the project, and click 'Failure Conditions'. This gives you a place whwre you can  add a failure condition on a metric change. One of the available metric changes is 'Percentage of line coverage'. You can set it so that the build fails if this is less the 0 difference from the last build.

[image]

Beware adding this though, especially if you have projects where the code coverage is not 100% already, as a refactoring which reduces the number of lines in the project and all of those lines happen to be covered by tests will result on the overall coverage going down, and a failing build despite not adding any new functionality.